Excluding a directory from git version tracking but using it in a GitHub workflow
I'm a technical writer working with DITA XML and using it to publish to HTML. I keep my DITA XML in Git on GitHub, and manually use a workflow in GitHub to publish the resulting HTML to an Azure static web page.
The problem: I want to track changes in the source code (.dita files) but not the output code (.html files). The HTML files are all in a subdirectory (/docs) but I cannot just add docs/ to .gitignore because the HTML files are then processed by the GitHub workflow to actually publish the page.
Is there any way to go around this? I found ways to ignore the subdirectory, to assume that it has not been changed, but in all such circumstances my commit would not include the resulting HTML and it would not be pushed to GitHub, and therefore I would not be able to publish the page.
My colleagues suggested that I move the transformation process (.dita to .html) to GitHub and include it in the workflow, but that is not possible, the transformation must be done on my machine due to the specifics of the software I use (it's based on DITA-OT but extends it and without those extentions, the styling of the resultant HTML would be off).
Any suggestions would be appreciated. It's not critical, just a nuisance, since each commit has around 400 files changed, while I may have just changed one small thing in one .dita file but had to rerun the transformation from scratch (and the transformation uses random IDs in HTML, so each resulting HTML batch is different).
Tried .gitignore, tried assume-unchanged, neither one of them seem to fit this. Found several threads on stackoverflow but they all apply to situations where the ignored content does not need to be available at the remote.
Note: my knowledge of git is very limited and I prefer to use the SourceTree GUI to manage it. Dammit, Jim, I'm a technical writer, not a developer! :D

Can you somehow influence those random IDs in HTML to make them less random? If not — can you write a program to remove the IDs so your HTML will be the same? Can you avoid generating HTMLs for unchanged source files?

Wow, this is a tricky one! But your colleagues are right: the typical solution is to build the site in a GitHub Action, so my approach would be to push this idea further, by looking for ways to install the extensions you have locally into the job workflow. I'd dig deep into this because otherwise I think you're back to committing all those trivially changed files each time.

Wild guess, though: does the process that generates odes random IDs let you specify a seed for its random number generator? If so, that might stabilize the ids...

Thanks for the ideas, unfortunately, it doesn't seem like this is possible, see https://www.oxygenxml.com/forum/feature-request-f42/topic24775.html -- the reason for these random IDs is for browsers not to serve changed pages from cache... I would rather avoid that problem cause I don't want users seeing outdated documentation (due to the cache) and then calling our support :(

Also @joanis moving the generation to GitHub is not likely since the editor that produces the HTML (nice how we like it) is a Windows commercial product.
The only solution I see, if there is no way to do it within GitHub, is .gitignore the output directory and find a way to publish the output directory from my machine straight to Azure without involving GitHub. May not be as convenient though as now (clicking "build"...).

Fair enough, licensing restrictions can certainly block you here. I'm sure Azure supports alternative automation mechanisms, maybe there's away to trigger the build and publish with one (or few) clicks right from your own machine.
